# Can not avoid duplicates using IF NOT EXIST statement

Tags: sql-server, debugging, vbscript, duplicates

I use the code below to insert data and avoid duplicated rows in SQL Server.
And it works just fine for me in test environment (local SQL Server), but after a few days in work environment (remote SQL server) I have found several duplicated rows in my table. I am wondering how it is possible? And the main question how can I debug this issue? Maybe there are some logs in SQL Server which show the history of executed commands?
Any suggestions are appreciated!

```vbs
SQLcmd = _
    "IF ( NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM " & TableName & " WHERE" & _
     " SSYS_ID = "          & SmartTags( "SSYS_ID" ) & _
     " AND TASK_ID = "      & SmartTags( "TASK_ID" ) & _
     " AND COPM_ID = "      & SmartTags( "COPM_ID" ) & _
     " AND SILAGE_ID = "    & SmartTags( "SILAGE_ID" ) & _
     " AND WCELL_ID = "     & SmartTags( "WCELL_ID" ) & _
     " ) ) " & _
    " BEGIN" & _
    " INSERT INTO " & TableName & _
            "([SSYS_ID]" & _
            ",[TASK_ID]" & _
            ",[COPM_ID]" & _
            ",[SILAGE_ID]" & _
            ",[RECIPE_ID]" & _
            ",[WCELL_ID]" & _
     "VALUES (" & _
            " " & SmartTags( "SSYS_ID" ) & _
            "," & SmartTags( "TASK_ID" ) & _
            "," & SmartTags( "COPM_ID" ) & _
            "," & SmartTags( "SILAGE_ID" ) & _
            "," & SmartTags( "RECIPE_ID" ) & _
            "," & SmartTags( "WCELL_ID" ) & _
            ")" & _
    " END"

    conn.Execute SQLcmd, RecordsAffected, adExecuteNoRecords
```

Comment: Could throw a primary key constraint in there and force the records to be unique.

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: Does the table you insert rows into has an `identity` (autoincrement) primary key? Btw, in the `IF` statement where you check if the row exists it looks like there's missing `RECIPE_ID`.

Comment: @Mislav Zic, yes the table has an identity (autoincrement) field ID, and this is the only one field which contains unique value after the issue - all other fields are duplicated.

Comment: Whtat is about `RECIPE_ID` - no I don not check it because it should not be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have described suggests there is an issue with multiple users trying to concurrently insert the same data into the table at the same time (i.e. `SSYS_ID`, `TASK_ID`, `COPM_ID`, `SILAGE_ID`, and `WCELL_ID`). In the single user dev/test environment where you, as the only user, test your code the problem can’t surface (or, is hard to reproduce). The fact that the problem manifested itself after you deployed your application to the multi-user production environment may indicate there is a large number of concurrent users inserting data into the table, so that the probability of multiple users trying to insert the same thing at the same time is high. Hence, you should carefully choose a solution that won’t hinder the database performance.

For example, say there are two users (i.e. transactions): a user A and a user B. At the same time both users start inserting the same data. So, the following might happen:

1. Both, the `User A` and the `User B` start inserting the same data
2. The `User A` checks if there is already a row with that data in the table. The data is not present, so the `User A` proceeds with inserting it.
3. The `User B` checks if there is already a row with that very same data in the table. The data still doesn’t exist, so the `User B` proceeds with inserting it as well.
4. The `User A` then carry on and inserts the data.
5. Also, the `User B` continues and inserts the same data
6. Now, there are two rows with the same data.

## The Solution

Here are several options you can use to solve this:

**The first option**, which I recommend, given the substantial number of concurrent users, is to simply enforce the business rule of having unique data at the database level by creating a unique constraint on columns (`SSYS_ID`, `TASK_ID`, `COPM_ID`, `SILAGE_ID`, `WCELL_ID`). In that case your code should have just the `INSERT` statement:

```
SQLcmd = _
    " INSERT INTO " & TableName & _
            "([SSYS_ID]" & _
            ",[TASK_ID]" & _
            ",[COPM_ID]" & _
            ",[SILAGE_ID]" & _
            ",[RECIPE_ID]" & _
            ",[WCELL_ID]" & _
     "VALUES (" & _
            " " & SmartTags( "SSYS_ID" ) & _
            "," & SmartTags( "TASK_ID" ) & _
            "," & SmartTags( "COPM_ID" ) & _
            "," & SmartTags( "SILAGE_ID" ) & _
            "," & SmartTags( "RECIPE_ID" ) & _
            "," & SmartTags( "WCELL_ID" ) & _
            ")" 

    conn.Execute SQLcmd, RecordsAffected, adExecuteNoRecords
```

Instead of checking `RecordsAffected` to see if the row is inserted or not, you should modify your code to check if a DB error occurred, in particular, the error 2627. (If you implement the business rule with a unique index instead, check for the error 2601; see [How to troubleshoot Error 2601 Cannot insert duplicate key row in object '%.*ls' with unique index '%.*ls'. The duplicate key value is %ls.](http://www.sqlserver-dba.com/2015/05/how-to-troubleshoot-error-2601-cannot-insert-duplicate-key-row-in-object-ls-with-unique-index-ls-the.html)).

This solution shouldn’t hurt database performance as much as the second solution below. It will incur some performance degradation of inserts and updates that goes into maintaining the unique index. It will also enforce the rule at the database level, so that whatever SQL statements are used to insert rows it will guarantee that duplicate rows will be rejected. It’s the design for today and for tomorrow.

**The second option** is to add table hints to the `SELECT` statement that checks if there is already a row. So, the code should look like:

```
IF (NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM YourTable WITH(UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK) 
    WHERE
        SSYS_ID = @SSYS_ID
        AND TASK_ID = @TASK_ID
        AND COPM_ID = @COPM_ID
        AND SILAGE_ID = @SILAGE_ID
        AND WCELL_ID = @WCELL_ID
))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO YourTable(
         SSYS_ID
        ,TASK_ID
        ,COPM_ID
        ,SILAGE_ID
        ,RECIPE_ID
        ,WCELL_ID
    ) VALUES (
         @SSYS_ID
        ,@TASK_ID
        ,@COPM_ID
        ,@SILAGE_ID
        ,@RECIPE_ID
        ,@WCELL_ID
    )
END
```

Notice here `UPDLOCK` and `HOLDLOCK`. They lock the table with the intent to update it until the end of a transaction, in your case it should be until the ADO command finishes. So, the `SELECT` locks the table, checks if there’s already a row in the table and then the command proceeds, if necessary, to insert the row, causing other concurrent commands to wait with their `SELECT`s until the insert is done and the command is finished. For example, the flow of events might be like the following:

1. Both, the `User A` and the `User B` start inserting the same data
2. The `User A` locks the table and checks if there is already a row with that data
3. The `User B` waits the table to get unlocked to proceed with its check
4. There is no row with the data, so the `User A` inserts the data.
5. The `User A`’s command (transaction) finishes and the table gets unlocked
6. As the table gets unlocked now the `User B`’s locks the table and checks if there is already a row in the table
7. There already exists the row in the table, so `User B` doesn’t insert that duplicate row
8. The `User B`’s command (transaction) finishes and the table gets unlocked

Use this solution with caution, and only if creating the unique constraint or unique index is not possible in your situation, since it will degrade your database performance due to locking of the table. These commands (lock-check-then-insert) will block all other operations on the table: other inserts, updates as well as other selects with update intents. Also, if you start a transaction explicitly in your code (ADO’s `BeginTrans`), make sure you commit (ADO’s `CommitTrans`) or rollback (ADO’s `RollbackTrans`) the transaction in any case (regularly or in an exception/error handler), or else a non-terminated transaction will keep holding the lock on the table blocking all other further operations on the table.

**Two more options** that are basically just variations of the previous one: `MERGE` and `INSERT INTO SELECT`. They both don't solve the concurrency problem unless they are modified with the same table hints. Thus, with the table hints the performance suffers due to locking and blocking like in the previous solution. They are:

**`MERGE` with `HOLDLOCK`:**

```
MERGE YourTable WITH (HOLDLOCK) AS dst 
USING (
    SELECT
         @SSYS_ID AS SSYS_ID
        ,@TASK_ID AS TASK_ID
        ,@COPM_ID AS COPM_ID
        ,@SILAGE_ID AS SILAGE_ID
        ,@WCELL_ID AS WCELL_ID
) AS src
ON dst.SSYS_ID = src.SSYS_ID AND
   dst.TASK_ID = src.TASK_ID AND
   dst.COPM_ID = src.COPM_ID AND
   dst.SILAGE_ID = src.SILAGE_ID AND
   dst.WCELL_ID = src.WCELL_ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
         SSYS_ID
        ,TASK_ID
        ,COPM_ID
        ,SILAGE_ID
        ,RECIPE_ID
        ,WCELL_ID
    ) VALUES (
         @SSYS_ID
        ,@TASK_ID
        ,@COPM_ID
        ,@SILAGE_ID
        ,@RECIPE_ID
        ,@WCELL_ID
    );
```

Note that it has only `HOLDLOCK`. It doesn’t need `UPDLOCK` since it issues update locks by itself.

**`INSERT INTO SELECT` with `UPDLOCK` and `HOLDLOCK`:**

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(
     SSYS_ID
    ,TASK_ID
    ,COPM_ID
    ,SILAGE_ID
    ,RECIPE_ID
    ,WCELL_ID
) 
SELECT
     @SSYS_ID
    ,@TASK_ID
    ,@COPM_ID
    ,@SILAGE_ID
    ,@RECIPE_ID
    ,@WCELL_ID
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * 
        FROM YourTable WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
        WHERE
            SSYS_ID = @SSYS_ID
            AND TASK_ID = @TASK_ID
            AND COPM_ID = @COPM_ID
            AND SILAGE_ID = @SILAGE_ID
            AND WCELL_ID = @WCELL_ID
    )
```

#### Command Timeouts

A timeout can happen because of high server load and slow response, a long running query, or sometimes just because of a slow connection. It happens on a client, not on a server. When it happens, the client notifies the server about the timeout and then the server ends currently executing statement at the best time it decides, but it doesn't rollback the transaction (unless the `XACT_ABORT` is `ON`).

In your case, probably due to the high server load, a timeout occurs just after the insert completed and while the transaction is still being committed (automatically). Then when you immediately retrigger the command it manages to execute the first `SELECT` statement that checks if the row exists while the previous command’s transaction is still being committed.

To prevent this to happen you should explicitly start a transaction in your code, invoke the command, and then commit the transaction if the command was successful, or rollback the transaction on a timeout and then retry. Be aware that committing or rolling back a transaction can also timeout when the server load is high or the transaction is large and needs time to commit or rollback, but the timeout won’t cause the commit or the rollback to be stopped or undone -
 they succeed always.

## In Summary...

1. Make inserts of new rows reliable. Either, create the unique constraint or, if the unique constraint is not option for you, go with one of those inserts with table hints.
2. Explicitly start a transaction (`BeginTrans`), execute the command (`Execute`), and then commit the transaction on success (`CommitTrans`) or rollback it on failure (`RollbackTrans`).
3. If a timeout happens rollback the transaction and try again.
4. Use parameters in your command.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for detailed help. The first option looks like the best solution in my case. The only thing I should do before implementing it - is remove all dulpicated rows I guess.
What is about multiple user trying to insert simulteniosly - it is a bit wierd, becouse I have only one PC with four programmed events. All of that four envents are supposed to insert unique data.
In case there is not any responce from the SQL Server - event must be repeated.

Comment: Yes, you're right. You should remove duplicates before creating unique constraint/index.

Comment: You mean, you don't have many users (or any) using your app simultaneously, but instead you have just one PC firing 4 types of events each inserting into the same table but on a remote SQL Server. When a SQL command timeout you resend the same data again? Is there a high volume of these events fired? Are the remote SQL Server used for other purposes, by other users, etc.? Load on the server is high? Queries are not responsive?

Comment: yes your description of the application is correct. Each event is triggered about 6-12 times per minute inserting about 20-30 fields of type REAL into remote SQL Server.
In case of timeout, the event is retriggered. SQL Server is used for other purposes and by other users, and I actually cannot evaluate the load - all I have is access to my DB.
Usually queries are quite responsive however, in my logs there are some records about timeout, which I suppose, caused duplicated rows.
Recently I have my code rewritten using MERGE keyword as mentioned above. We will see...

Comment: Apparently it's a timeout coupled with an occasional high sever load. Quick workaround could be to just prolong the timeout period or retry after some time. Nevertheless,  I've updated the answer to cover timeouts and two more options, so that you can make it work reliably if needed.  :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I agree with the statement above about sql injection. You should switch to a parameterized query.

Second this is not thread safe. It is possible that 2 threads try to insert the same values at the same time. Both threads do the `IF` check and do not find a match, then both insert. This sounds like what is happening in a high volume production environment.  You need to execute it in a single statement, like `MERGE`

```
DECLARE
    @SSYS_ID INTEGER
    , @TASK_ID INTEGER
    , @COPM_ID INTEGER
    , @SILAGE_ID INTEGER
    , @RECIPE_ID INTEGER
    , @WCELL_ID INTEGER

MERGE TABLENAME AS target
USING
(
    SELECT
        @SSYS_ID AS SSYS_ID
        , @TASK_ID AS TASK_ID
        , @COPM_ID AS COPM_ID
        , @SILAGE_ID AS SILAGE_ID
        , @RECIPE_ID AS RECIPE_ID
        , @WCELL_ID AS WCELL_ID
) AS source
    ON
    (
        target.SSYS_ID = source.SSYS_ID
        AND target.TASK_ID = source.TASK_ID
        AND target.COPM_ID = source.COPM_ID
        AND target.SILAGE_ID = source.SILAGE_ID
        AND target.WCELL_ID = source.WCELL_ID
    )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (SSYS_ID, TASK_ID, COPM_ID, SILAGE_ID, WCELL_ID)
    VALUES (source.SSYS_ID, source.TASK_ID, source.COPM_ID, source.SILAGE_ID, source.WCELL_ID)
;
```

Comment: Thank you @Craig K. I will use parameterized query indeed.
Could you please explain more detailed: the second thread can exist if I execute my code too often?

Comment: The race condition occurs when separate threads run this function at the same time. Most production environments are set up to handle a large number of requests simultaneously, it does this by assigning separate threads to each request.  
Let's take a store front web site as an example. If shopper A and shopper B both try to purchase items at the same time, your webserver will not make shopper B wait until shopper A is complete. Instead each shopper will instead be serviced by their own thread, running concurrently in a multi-CPU/multi-core environment.